# Java add global JTextPane styles/attributes?

Tags: java, swing, styles, jtextpane

I want to add a global AttributeSet to my JTextPane.

I found this:

```
SimpleAttributeSet style = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setLeftIndent(style, 20);
StyleConstants.setFirstLineIndent(style, -20);
```

From http://java-sl.com/tip_hanging_first_line.html

I'm wondering how I can set the "default stylesheet"? (not using HTML). I then tried this:

```
StyleContext style = new StyleContext();
Style s = style.addStyle("test", null);
StyleConstants.setForeground(s, Color.BLUE);
StyledDocument d = (StyledDocument) console.getOutputField().getDocument();
```

From http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneStylesExample1.htm without luck.

I know StyledDocument has specific properties for setting stuff like foreground colour - which is why this may not work - but can anyone point me as to how to use the other style attributes? Such as the left indent and first line indent.

Answer (score 3):

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet style = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setLeftIndent(style, 20);
StyleConstants.setFirstLineIndent(style, -20);
StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.BLUE);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), style, true);
```

Comment: This isn't showing up for me, windows 7 jdk 1.6? Also, will this style apply even after I add more text to the document?

Comment: Works for me over various versions of Windows and JDK. Post your SSCCE that shows the problem.

Comment: So it wasn't working when I was setting the style after I had appended text. Although it works now that I stick before I append/insert any text. Event if I do `doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 0, style, false);`. Know why it works even if I set the length to be 0?

Comment: Works for me if I set the attributes after I append text because it applies the attributes to all the text. Still don't see a SSCCE so I can't comment on your problem.

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting a concise example to show the problem (it works if I make a really simple app) (I'm working on it). But in the mean time, why does `setParagraphAttributes(0, 0...)` work? (apply to "0" characters)